# custom extenders KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So I've been trying to work this out but to no success.

Basically I am trying to implement an extender to validate my object in knockout when filling in a form.
I got the object bound like this:

```
 noVatReason: ko.observable().extend({ noVatCheck: "You need to fill in a reason!" })
```

This is a basic check to see if a string is filled in or not. The code for the validator looks like this:

```
ko.extenders.noVatCheck = function (target, message) {
        target.hasError = ko.observable();
        target.validationMessage = ko.observable();

        function validate(newValue) {
            target.hasError(newValue ? false : true);
            target.validationMessage(newValue ? "" : message);
        }

        validate(target());
        target.subscribe(validate);

        return target;
    };
```

This does not work sadly enough yet it is almost a full copy of the extender example on the knockout documentation.

Can someone figure out what I am doing wrong? I believe it to be something super silly but I'm just looking right next to it I guess.

Comment: What do you mean on does not work? How do you use your `noVatReason` in your view? How do you set in your viewmodel?

Comment: The noVatReason is bound to a textarea which is unabled when a checkbox is checked. What does not happen is the validation, so every part of this.

Comment: can u put up fiddle?

Comment: Second @DevelopmentIsMyPassion. [The code as posted works fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkw5L5pd/1/) Please edit your question, include a repro.

Comment: maybe you're just not binding `validationMessage` to anything to see the extender working?  Either way, just set breakpoints in your extender to see it being called, don't be afraid of developer tools :)